# Calling Stored procedure in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, spring-mvc

One way to call a stored procedure in hibernate is listed below but my  procedure in real life environment internally calls DB link so obviously there will not be a class associated with the procedure.

What I mean to say is

`addEntity(Stock.class)`: here `Stock` is class with which `createSQLQuery()` will map its output, but in my case  there will be no class since my procedure is accessing DB Link(Other database tables).

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(
    "CALL GetStocks(:stockCode)")
    .addEntity(Stock.class)
    .setParameter("stockCode", "7277");

List result = query.list();
for(int i=0; i<result.size(); i++){
    Stock stock = (Stock)result.get(i);
    System.out.println(stock.getStockCode());
}
```

My Question

1. How do I call that procedure without (Entity) Class?
2. My procedure is selecting  10 columns from other databases through
   DB link and  returning its data which I am putting in the list after
   execution of the procedure.  How do I implement the above scenario in
   Hibernate?

Comment: _How do I call .._ I think you can use `SimpleJdbcCall` for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SimpleJdbcCall` like to this

```
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate);

simpleJdbcCall.withProcedureName("GetStocks");
simpleJdbcCall.declareParameters(new SqlParameter("stockCode",
            OracleTypes.VARCHAR));

MapSqlParameterSource map = new MapSqlParameterSource();
map = new MapSqlParameterSource();
map.addValue("stockCode", "7277");

Map<String, Object> result = simpleJdbcCall.execute(map);
```

Comment: I am actually converting  my project from  jdbc to hibernate I want to take advantage of hibernate ....thanks by the way